# Cocoa Touch Updating UITableView from Core Data

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, uitableview

Say I have two `UIViewControllers`, all working under a `UINavigationController`:

1. `RootViewController` hosts a UITableView which contains a list of domain names.
2. `CodeViewController` shows a domain.

A user can view any domain they like; once the domain is viewed in `CodeViewController`, the name is added to the store via Core Data.

When the user hits the back button to return to the `RootViewController`, I want that new domain to appear in the `UITableView`. I can't make this happen.

I've attempted several techniques like flushing out the array that supplies the values to the table; I've put my CD calls into `viewWillAppear` (currently in `viewDidLoad`).

On the Mac, I'd just use bindings to bind the table to the CD model, but how would you do it on the iPhone? I'm stumped!

Thanks,
Aaron.

Comment: Please post your `-viewWillAppear:` code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically you implement an NSFetchedResultsController in between your Core Data data and your table view.

It has delegate methods such `controllerDidChangeContent:` to inform you that the content has changed and the table view needs updating (you could call `reloadData` on the table view).

Comment: I'd never heard of NSFetchedResultsController, and with some fussing around, I got it to work! Thanks so much for your help! I found these two Apple docs helped: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html and http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate